# R Subsetting a data.frame when 2 columns have different values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data.frame like this:

```
          Type1 rep1    Type2 rep2    stat p.value
    17    DqSAD    1 rnzDqSAD    9  3.7946  0.0101
    18    DqSAD    1    DqSAD   10 -0.5278  0.6428
    19    DqSAD    1 rnzDqSAD   10  0.4111  0.2231
    20 rnzDqSAD    1    DqSAD    2 -0.3111  0.5085
    21 rnzDqSAD    1 rnzDqSAD    2 -0.8904  0.9080
```

and I would like to subset it when the columns Type1 & Type 2 have different values. I mean in an automatic way, not explicitly checking for this particular values like Type1=="DqSAD" & Type2=="rnzDqSAD" I remember this could be done with sql, but I don't figure out how to do it in R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by finding the rows where `Type1` and `Type2` are not equal with the `!=` logical operator.  If `df` is the data,

```
> df[with(df, Type1 != Type2), ]
#       Type1 rep1    Type2 rep2    stat p.value
# 17    DqSAD    1 rnzDqSAD    9  3.7946  0.0101
# 19    DqSAD    1 rnzDqSAD   10  0.4111  0.2231
# 20 rnzDqSAD    1    DqSAD    2 -0.3111  0.5085
```